# Alternate method to prove this series in a better way

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation

Prove that $\frac{1.2 + 2.3 + 3.4 + .....+ n(n + 1)}{n(n + 3)} \ge \frac{n + 1}{4}$ for $n\ge1$

My attempt : 
 Breaking the series into two different series 
$$ S_1 = \sum_{i = 0}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n + 1) (2n + 1)}{6}$$

$$ S_2 = \sum_{i = 0}^n i = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$$

Now $$S_1 + S_2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3}$$

Writing down LHS and RHS we get :

$$\frac{(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3(n + 3)} \ge \frac{(n + 1)}{4}$$

Multiplying both sides by $$\frac{12}{n + 1}$$ we get :

$$4(n + 1) \ge 3$$

This will always be true $$. ^ . _ . n\ge1$$

Hence proved.

Is there a mistake in my method? Is there a better method to prove this?

Comment: First, what you have to prove is $\frac{1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+\cdots + n(n+1)}{n(n+3)}\ge \frac{n+1}{4}$ given $n\ge 1$, not showing $n\ge 1$ given $\frac{1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+\cdots + n(n+1)}{n(n+3)}\ge \frac{n+1}{4}$. Second, you do not divide $12/(n+1)$, but multiply it. Third, if we multiply $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3(n+3)}$ by $12/(n+1)$, then $4n(n+2)/(n+3)$ appears, not $4(n+1)$.

Comment: @choco_addicted is it looking correct now?

Comment: working backwards we have $$\begin{array}{lll}
n&\ge&1\\
4n-3n&\ge&9-8\\
4n+8&\ge&3n+9\\
4(n+2)&\ge&3(n+3)\\
\frac{n+2}{3(n+3)}&\ge&\frac{1}{4}\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k (k+1)
= 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{k+1}{2}
= 2 \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \binom{k}{2}
= 2 \binom{n+2}{3}
= \dfrac13 n (n+1) (n+2)
$$

Therefore
$$
\frac{1\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3 + \cdots + n(n + 1)}{n(n + 3)}
= \frac{ n (n+1) (n+2)}{3n(n + 3)}
= (n+1)\frac{n+2}{3(n + 3)}
\ge (n+1) \frac{1}{4}
$$
because
$$
\frac{n+2}{3(n + 3)} \ge \dfrac14
$$
for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: But at $n$ = 1 LHS will be 1/4 which is less than RHS

Comment: @user109256, it was a typo. fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\left(\frac{n+2}{n+3}\right)$ increases, $\left(\frac{n+2}{n+3}\right)$ has the minimum $\frac{3}{4}$ when $n=1$. Thus we get
\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3n(n+3)} &= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3(n+3)}\\
&= \frac{n+1}{3}\cdot \frac{n+2}{n+3}\\
&\ge \frac{n+1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't understood your method.

Comment: Notify me where you are stuck, then I'll add some description.

Comment: why have you replaced \frac{n + 2}{n + 3} by \frac{3\4}

Comment: @user109256 I edited my post. Can you understand now? Or are there other doubts?